# Why is this Back to the Future related question linked with this Lord of the Rings related question?

Tags: bug

Why are these two questions linked?

- [LOTR related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90940/what-did-aragorn-do-with-his-sword-between-the-battles-of-pelennor-fields-and-mo?lq=1)
- [Back to the Future related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105102/where-is-hill-valley?lq=1)?

Is it just me or they shouldn't they be linked?

Comment: Because I like to advertise my past answers in my new answers :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All it takes is one link *anywhere* on either page to link two questions. The link could be in the question, any answer or even any comment. And the link itself can link to either the question, any answer or any comment on the other page.

In this case it is due to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105103/143) by @randal'thor which ends with this paragraph:

> For the [pedants](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90940/what-did-aragorn-do-with-his-sword-between-the-battles-of-pelennor-fields-and-mo/90943#90943): under the rules in effect in 1989 (after the 1986 enactment of PL 99-359 to amend the Uniform Time Act, but before the Energy Policy Act of 2005 - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States#History_of_DST_in_the_United_States)), US Daylight Saving Time *would* have ended on the last Sunday in October instead of the first Sunday in November. In 2015 this is 25 October, which is still after 21 October, so Daylight Saving Time would still have been in effect and the answer remains the same.

The **pedants** word links to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90940/what-did-aragorn-do-with-his-sword-between-the-battles-of-pelennor-fields-and-mo/90943#90943).

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I missed that.